# Como criar menu no Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou querendo criar um menu parecido com este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia me explicar como montar? Gostaria de alguma dica.

Comment: Por favor não use esse menu, pois acredito que esse seja um `design ultrapassado` e não recomendo. Aqui está uma forma de criar como deseja: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/

Comment: @Reiksiel O que você quer dizer com design ultrapassado? O exemplo que você citou vai de acordo com o que diz a [documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu), que por sinal foi de onde o OP tirou a imagem que deu como exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guilherme é isso mesmo que o @Piovezan disse o proprio android ajusta a quantidade de acordo com a tela, mas da uma olhada aqui [Implementing Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) na própria documentação do Android.

Pois esse menu utiliza o botão "menu" do aparelho e hoje em dia vários modelos não tem mais. Com isso pode gerar problemas de navegação com o usuário.

Os modelos da motorola e alguns Galaxy Tab com Android 4.x já estão sem este botão.

[image: Exemplo Menu]

No novo modelo você pode criar um menu assim:

Aqui no grupo [android-br](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidbrasil-dev/Jm4kBS_Q534) tem uma discussão sobre, e mais links também.

Vale a pena tentar.

Comment: Em alguns modelos o botão menu é substituído pelo botão virtual de action overflow (item 3 [desta imagem](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar@2x.png)). Para disponibilizar esse botão ao usuário é preciso que suas activities tenham uma `Action Bar`. Esta é uma possível tendência em outros aparelhos, mas a funcionalidade do menu deve sempre existir de alguma forma na interface com o usuário, mesmo sem o botão físico.

Answer (score 4):

Você está tendo alguma dificuldade específica? Porque senão, basta criar um arquivo `res/menu/menu.xml` com os itens de menu tendo cada item um título e um ícone drawable, como exemplificado na [própria documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Em aparelhos que não possuem botão físico de menu, é recomendado que você acrescente uma `Action Bar` a suas activities e use o botão virtual de action overflow (item 3 [desta imagem](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar@2x.png)) como botão de menu.

Comment: estou querendo criar como da imagem colocar os itens do menu um do lado do outro tipo 2x2

Comment: @Guilherme Acho que isso é montado pelo Android automaticamente conforme o espaço disponível na tela, não estou a par de nenhuma configuração para definir como os itens vão aparecer exceto pela ordem.